# Java - How to pass the class of a generic type into a method

Tags: java, scala, generics

The method in JavaSparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD takes class as a parameter.

In scala I was able to use the method like so:

```
sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(job.getConfiguration,
      classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[AvroFlumeEvent]],
      classOf[AvroKey[AvroFlumeEvent]],
      classOf[NullWritable])
```

How do i do that in java?

How do I pass the class of `AvroKeyInputFormat<AvroFlumeEvent>` into the method.

The closest I got was:

```
        Class<AvroKeyInputFormat<AvroFlumeEvent>> inputFormatClass;
        Class<AvroKey<AvroFlumeEvent>> keyClass;

        JavaPairRDD<AvroKey<AvroFlumeEvent>, NullWritable> flumeEvents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hadoopConf,
                inputFormatClass,
                keyClass,
                NullWritable.class);
```

However, now it is complaining that inputFormatClass may not have been initialized.  I think I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Java are either `null`, or an instance. Your variable `inputFormatClass` is neither `null` nor an instance, so you can't do anything to it until you initialize it. That's what it's complaining about.

As for passing the class in, you can do:

```
Class<AvroKeyInputFormat> clazz = AvroKeyInputFormat.class
```

Generic types are not stored at runtime - they are only used for verification. That's why you can't have a class of `AvroKeyInputFormat<AvroFlumeEvent>`

Comment: @Sam_Sun thanks...one of these days I'll find out what java-generics are good for...